# Inconsistent cPickle

Tags: python, pickle

Why does the following code produce an error when run as a script?  It doesn't produce an error when run in an interactive shell (cut-and-paste).

```
import cPickle as pickle

val1 = dict(fooblah=[], xy=[])
pickval1 = pickle.dumps(val1, protocol=2)

val2 = pickle.loads(pickval1)
assert val1 == val2

pickval2 = pickle.dumps(val2, protocol=2)
assert pickval1 == pickval2, (pickval1, pickval2)
```

The difference in the pickles is below:

```
$ python /tmp/picklefun.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/picklefun.py", line 10, in <module>
    assert pickval1 == pickval2, (pickval1, pickval2)
AssertionError: ('\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x07fooblahq\x02]U\x02xyq\x03]u.',
                 '\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x07fooblah]U\x02xy]u.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the line

```
val1 = dict(fooblah=[], xy=[])
```

with

```
exec "val1 = dict(fooblah=[], xy=[])"
```

Then the asserts pass again.

Why??  The answer lies deep inside the mysteries of cPickle.  It has an optimization that looks if some objects have a reference counter less than 2, and avoids a few bytes in that case (normally used to detect cycles or multiple appearances of the same possibly large string).  This is about the string objects "fooblah" and "xy".  In the case of `exec` or when running interactively, by the time you pickle, the only references left to the strings are in the dictionary; the reference counter is 1, so cPickle avoids a few bytes.  But if you write the example as a module, then the module is still alive at that time, and it keeps another reference to the strings used as constants.

**EDIT** to clarify: the second time we pickle, we'll pickle a dictionary which has always fresh keys coming from the unpickling -- reference counter 1.  So the assert passes if and only if the keys where also of reference counter 1 the first time.

Comment: This can be double checked by replacing the eval with:
```
    val1 = dict()
    exec 'val1["fooblah"] = []'
    exec 'val1["xy"] = []'
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be caused by `cPickle` because it doesn't happen using plain-old `pickle` (I was able to reproduce your error).

That's Why, Level 1...I'll keep researching because it's an interesting find!

Update:

The cPickle docs (esp. footnotes) guarantee that objects will always be /read/ correctly but no guarantee is made (or reserved against) that the serialized data is always equal. Probably not unexpected behavior, but worth noticing.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle

Comment: I've also reproduced: Python 2.7.3 on Windows RT. `cPickle` fails; `pickle` does not.

Comment: Good to know you're able to reproduce it.  There are a couple of questions to answer (1) why is pickval1 != pickval2, and (2) why does it produce an error when run as a script but not when run interactively.  The second one is more troubling IMHO.

Comment: The fact that the results of `pickle.loads` are equivalent even though the serialized versions are different makes me worry less about (2). It is very interesting though, and hopefully someone with more understanding of the difference you found can enlighten us. But I will rest easy knowing that both strings represent the same object, which is hopefully all that matters.